# changing date output from sql from yyyy/mm/dd to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: mysql

Hello im trying to changing the date output from sql from yyyy/mm/dd to dd/mm/yyyy

the date wont get saved in mySQL when I enter the date via a datepicker on my form. (wil input only 0000-00-00)

If I enter the date manually into MySQL then It will only show the date of today.

Im using the folowing code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM overboekingen") 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
echo '<td>' . $row['datum_overboeking'] = date('d-m-Y') . '</td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with this type solution

```
$TodayDate = "2014-03-07"; //OR the date from database. It means the date you will get from database
$FormatedDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($TodayDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can put the conditions

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM overboekingen") 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
{
   $databaseDate = $row['YOUR DATABASE DATE FIELD NAME']; 
   $FormatedDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($databaseDate));
   echo '<td>' . $row['datum_overboeking'] = $FormatedDate . '</td>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im one step further and I can now insert the data correctly in the database, only it doesnt show the date from mySQL correctly when I echo in in my webapplication when it pulls it out SQL again.

It seems this piece of code is not correct:

```
echo '<td>' . $row['datum_overboeking'] = strtotime($row), date('m-d-Y') . '</td>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with this procedure to display the date from database with required date format

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM overboekingen") 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
{
   $databaseDate = $row['YOUR DATABASE DATE FIELD NAME']; 
   $FormatedDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($databaseDate));
   echo '<td>' . $row['datum_overboeking'] = $FormatedDate . '</td>';
}
```

Answer (score -2):

May this will help you

```
$TodayDate = "2014-03-07"; //OR the date from database. It means the date you will get from database
$FormatedDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($TodayDate));
```

Comment: One question. In the echo statement the date you want to show that will come from the database or you want to display the current date

Comment: The date will come from mysql wich is inserted via a datepicker on a seperated form

Comment: I think you've answer. Just give that with correct explanation.